# Iterate through NSMutableArray and change property of object

Tags: ios, loops, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` with 20 cards, colored red in this example.

The `Card` object has a property called `playable`. If the card is playable it holds the value `IsPlayable`, and if not, `IsNotPlayable`. The `Card` object also has a property `value`, from 1 up until 20.

The card with value 11 always is `IsPlayable` and if the difference between the next card and the current card is 1 (`cardUp/ cardDown`) I change the `Card` `playable` property to `IsPlayable`.

Let's say I have 5 `Card` objects in my array (called `_redPlayerCards`) when I start the game; 11, 2, 3, 13 and 9. When I draw a card from stack it gets added to `_redPlayerCards` and here is where I get varying results with the loop I created.

When I draw a `Card` with value of 10, the `playable` property of cards 10 and 9 get changed to `IsPlayable`, so 11, 10 and 9 `IsPlayable`. But, if I draw a `Card` with value 12 after, `Card` 12 and 13 do not get changed to `IsPlayable`, but stay `IsNotPlayable`. Only after I play value 11, value 12 gets changed to `IsPlayable`.

I really have no idea what is going wrong. It looks like every value under 11 is working fine and changing the `playable` property to `IsPlayable` and every value above 11 is not changing the `playable` property to `IsPlayable`. It only changes it if I play a card (put a card on the table `redTableCards` which is also an `NSMutableArray`). What is wrong with the code?

The `Card` with `value` 11 gets changed to `IsPlayable` outside the method. The rest is changed by this code:

```
//Playable red cards
NSMutableArray *playableRedCards = [NSMutableArray array];
Card *redPlayerCard = [[Card alloc]init];
BOOL changedRed = YES;
for(int x = 0; x < [_redPlayerCards count]; x++) {
    redPlayerCard = [_redPlayerCards objectAtIndex:x];
    while (changedRed) {
        changedRed = NO;
        for (redPlayerCard in _redPlayerCards) {
            NSNumber *cardValue = redPlayerCard.value;
            if (redPlayerCard.playable == IsPlayable) {
                [playableRedCards addObject:redPlayerCard.value];
                //NSLog(@"red is playable");

            } else {
                NSNumber *cardUp = @(cardValue.integerValue + 1);
                NSNumber *cardDown = @(cardValue.integerValue - 1);
                if ([playableRedCards containsObject:cardUp] || [playableRedCards containsObject:cardDown] || [[[Game game] redTableCards] containsObject:cardUp] || [[[Game game] redTableCards] containsObject:cardDown]) {
                    changedRed = YES;
                    redPlayerCard.playable = IsPlayable;
                    [playableRedCards addObject:redPlayerCard.value];
                    //NSLog(@"playable reds: %@", playableRedCards);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is a lot to read for this question so it's really confusing if i may help to have you optimize your question so that it's understandable. Change the "for (int x = 0; x < value; x++)" to "for ( Card *redPlayerCard in self.rePlayerCards)" and change your if statements so they only hold variables, instead of "[playableRedCards containsObject:cardUp]" have BOOL playableRedCards ContainCardUp = [playableRedCards containsObject:cardUp]" and then "if (playableRedCardsContainCardUp)" it will help not lose focus of the question.

Comment: It looks to me like the `playable` property should just hold a BOOL.

Comment: When does this bit of code run? Is this every time a card is played, drawn, both?

Comment: I agree with the other commenters - this is quite confusing - instead of continually updating a property of the card, perhaps you could create an isPlayalable:card method on your card object that returns a Boolean to indicate if this card is playable against the card argument?

Comment: Why not set the initial array up with known values and step through the code in the debugger. Presumably you know what route through the code a card with value 12 would take - where does it do something you hadn't planned?

Comment: I think I figured it out myself, but I am not sure yet, just need some more testing. I moved the allocation and initiation of the NSMA `playableRedCards` outside the method. Because I call this method every time I draw or play a card, the NSMA gets created over and over again, resulting in faulty results. I'll do some more testing before I am completely confident. Thanks anyway for your help!